# Lenovo ryzen 4500U laptop won't wake up after suspend in ubuntu 22.04/20.04

Tags: suspend, 22.04, amdgpu, amd-processor, amd-ryzen

So, when i suspend my laptop (either lid or suspend option) it doesn't wake up afterwards. Screen is black, power button and keyboard are lighted up, but there is no response (caps or numlck do not respond after pressing).

I am facing this issue for months now. I was using ubuntu 20.04 and i was hoping this issue would be resolved after upgrading to ubuntu 22.04 (clean install) but the issue remains. I know there is a ton of posts about this issue but i still cannot resolve it.

Dim screen from the power save options after doing nothing works fine for me. The laptop responds properly so it seems that it is another issue.

Running sudo apt install gnome-screensaver didn't resolve it.

I tried modifying the handlelid option at the /etc/ststemd/login.conf file. Currently using it with defaults.

I turned off fast startup on win10.

I tried enabling/disabling a bunch of cofiguration options from BIOS settings.

**Edit: Irrelevant for AMD-Applies on nvidia graphics**:  I edited the etc/default/grub line to: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.blacklist=1" from "quiet splash" (currently changed back to default)

**My configuration is the following:**

Lenovo thinkbook g2 ARE laptop

Dual boot with win10 in different SSDs

CPU: Ryzen 4500 (integrated graphics)

kernel: 5.15.0-56-generic (older or newer kernels didnt resolve the issue)

BIOS: up to date

wayland (xorg didnt resolve the issue)

**PS1.** A friend of mine has a quite new lenovo laptop with ryzen 5500U (ubuntu 20.04 - same kernel) and suspend works fine. Seems to me that if there was a bug to be fixed from ubuntu it must have been fixed already.

**PS2.** I am a noob in linux so go easy on me. I would appreciate detailed answers so i can understand what to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Very likely NOT something OS/software related. If there's an UEFI update (yes, UEFI is what you have, not BIOS that is effectively deprecated since more than a decade ago) you should apply it and test again. Side note, you added a boot parameter that isn't applicable - you don't have Nvidia graphics. In this case is irrelevant - it does absolutely nothing, good or bad - but it could have made it worse. Make sure you know what you're doing when changing those settings.

Comment: Ok so my uefi is up to date. I was just using a wrong word for it. Did i get that right? About nvidia you are right. I suspected it had to do with nvidia specifically so i tried it and then changed it back to default.

Comment: The point is if you don't have Nvidia then you don't use those Nvidia specific parameters.